# Convex multiple variables optimization problem with constraints in python

Tags: python, optimization, constraint

I am currently trying to implement the following optimization problem in python (in order to resolve it with scipy.optimize.minimize).

[image]

Please note that $\alpha$ is given, $T$ is the number of generated random values (i.e. via Monte Carlo simulation, also given). Variables $x,\  z,\ \gamma$ should be vectors of different dimension and are sub-products of the problem.

The function $f(x,y)$ is equal to -$y^T \cdot x$ ($y$ is a matrix $(n,t)$ random values generated using MonteCarlo technique - fitting a distribution, pandas). Variable `val` is a pandas data frame with all the observed data.

Unfortunately I am facing different problems while trying to solve it. Can anyone be so kind to evaluate my code and maybe suggest me how to code it correctly?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
import scipy.stats as sts
import pandas as pd

def objective(x, alpha, t):
    #
    return x[1] + (1 / (1 - alpha) * t) * np.sum(x[2])

def problem(val, t = 10, alpha = 0.9):
    #
    y = []
    
    for simbolo in val.columns:
        loc, scale = sts.gumbel_l.fit(val[simbolo])
        y.append(sts.gumbel_l.rvs(loc, scale, t))
        
    init = np.array(([1 / len(val.columns)] * len(val.columns), [1], [0] * t))
    constraints = [
        {"type": "ineq", "fun": lambda x: x[2]},
        {"type": "ineq", "fun": lambda x: np.dot(x[0].T, np.asarray(y)) + x[1] + x[2]},
        {"type": "eq", "fun": lambda x: np.dot(x[0].T, np.ones(len(val.columns))) - 1}
        ]
    bounds = (((0, None),) * len(rendimenti.columns), ((None, None),), ((None, None),) * t)
    args = (alpha, t)
        
    res = opt.minimize(
        objective,
        x0 = init,
        args = args,
        bounds = bounds, 
        constraints = constraints
    )
    
    return res['x']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    test = np.random.rand(400, 6)
    test = pd.DataFrame(test)
 
    print(problem(test, t = 3))
```

First of all I am facing problems in defining bounds for the variables that need to be determined  ($x,\  z,\ \gamma$) i.e.:

```
bounds = (((0, None),) * len(var.columns), ((None, None),), ((None, None),) * t)
```

which leads to the following error:

```
 File "main.py", line 250, in <module>
    problem(r)
  File "port.py", line 152, in vanilla_cvar
    res = opt.minimize(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 625, in minimize
    return _minimize_slsqp(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/slsqp.py", line 315, in _minimize_slsqp
    new_bounds = old_bound_to_new(bounds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_constraints.py", line 316, in old_bound_to_new
    lb, ub = zip(*bounds)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Secondly there is a problem in defining init like I did because it is converted in a numpy array by the optimizer and numpy arrays can not contain multiple arrays of different dimensions.

EDIT: as requested.

i.e with $t=3$ and $n = 6$ the matrix $y^T$ is $(3,6)$, the vector $x$ should be $(6,1)$, the vector $z$ should be $(3,1)$ and for what I have been able to understand from the paper $\gamma$ is a vector $(1,1)$.

EDIT: apparently the question has been closed. I do not know why considering it is about how to properly and practically solve multiple variables optimization given a statistical model (it is not about debugging). I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Couple requests: the expression $y \cdot x.T$ is ambiguous. You used the dot operator. What's the period for? And could you please list out all the sizes of each vector that you're expecting? It's my experience that in Python or MATLAB/Octave, knowing what you expect for vector sizes solves many problems just by matching things up properly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @AdrianKeister. I just edited the post adding the sizes of each vector. Specifically regarding the expression I am sorry it seems that I mystyped it - the correct formulation is  $f(x,y)=y^T\cdot x$

Comment: I believe your problem is a [linear program](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html), so there is no need to use the more general `minimize` function.

Comment: @Nipper can you please provide the full code for the others to reproduces the error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ping. I just added the full code.

Comment: Can you please link the original paper?

Comment: Sure @ping! Please consider the following link https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/57096/cvar-optimization-algorithms

Comment: Pls have a look at there: https://codeshare.io/5vD3ZD Double check that it makes sense. I converted the three parameters x, gamma, z into a single concatenated array

Comment: Re your edit: I don't see any statistical model in your post.  The question is explicitly about overcoming software problems and such questions are just as explicitly off topic here.

Comment: First of all I want to thank you very much @ping for taking the time to help me. Most kind. Regarding the optimization problem yes I am able to compile it without errors but unfortunately it is not working as it supposed be (the result is unstable even increasing $t$ and when it appears to converge $x$ it is equal to `init`).

Comment: @ping I noticed that you transposed $x$ rather than $y$ which leads to a different result. But the problem must be elsewhere..